# Fontello Glyph Font odd behaviour on Firefox, shows unicode codes instead of icons

Tags: css, firefox, webfonts, fontello

I have a webpage.
In its upper right corner I have some social icons. It shows okay in Chrome (both local and on the webserver), it shows **ok** in local FF, but on the **online** page I see the square placeholders with the Unicode codes inside.

Oddly enough, if i open Firebug and correct the fontello.css on the fly via *Source Edit*, the icons appear magically, or so it seems, and this even with trivial corrections like adding and then removing a whitespace.

This is really puzzling me. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see the images with FF...

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Yes, the problem has been solved. It was a header problem from the Apache servere. I'll close the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to solve this strange issue. Turned out it was an Apache problem, got the solution from: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems

I've added to my `.htaccess` the following lines:

If you are serving from Apache, you can add this to your `.htaccess` file to allow your site access to the fonts:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

and the font now is ok.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it for me. I added the `eot` extension too since that's used by fontello.

Comment: Where can I find my `.htaccess` (I assume it's a file?) in windows 7?

Comment: @Zarah The .htaccess file is not tied to an operating system, it is used for Apache server configuration in your web folders.