# Fontello pseudo class icons not showing in FF

Tags: css, fontello

The icons are not showing in Firefox and this only occurs sometimes.

CSS:

> ```
> .icon-glyph::before {
>     content: "";
> }
>
> @font-face{font-family:'fontello';src:url(../font/fontello.eot);src:url(../font/fontello.eot#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../font/fontello.woff) format("woff"),url(../font/fontello.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../font/fontello.svg) format("svg");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}
> ```

(the files referred at the font-face part are in place)

Is it the browser issue (since it is only in FF) or is there something wrong in the CSS?

Comment: Can you post a url?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636949/fontello-glyph-font-odd-behaviour-on-firefox-shows-unicode-codes-instead-of-ico?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. The url is http://www.nordoutlet.com/da/18636-guess-ur.html . But this issue is not all the time.

This link is not a solution, i have nginx not apache.